# Pandas bins with additional bin of ==0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to use the pandas bins with the range like below

```
tipBins = [1,5,10,15,20,25,30].
```

Also for some rides tip would be zero that doesn't fall under any range.
How to supply that value zero in the pandas bins.I need a partition of bins like below

```
==0
1-5
5-10
10-15
15-20
20-25
25-30
```

---

```
import numpy as np
tipBins = [1,5,10,15,20,25,30]
tipData=DataFrame(tipPercentage)
tip_data_names = ["No Tip", '1-5','5-10','10-15','15-20','20-25','25-30']
tipData['ranges'] = pd.cut(tipData['tipPercent'], tipBins, labels=tip_data_names)
td=tipData[['count','ranges']].groupby(['ranges']).sum().fillna(0)
sd.reset_index()
```

Should i have bins like this `tipBins = [0,0,1,5,10,15,20,25,30].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure the *tipPercentage* won't contain any negative numbers, you can add a negative number in the `tipBins`, for instance:

```
tipBins = [-1,1,5,10,15,20,25,30]
```

*Example*:

```
v = [0, 4, 7, 20, 26]    
tip_data_names = ["No Tip", '1-5','5-10','10-15','15-20','20-25','25-30']

import pandas as pd
pd.cut(v, tipBins, labels=tip_data_names)

# [No Tip, 1-5, 5-10, 15-20, 25-30]
# Categories (7, object): [No Tip < 1-5 < 5-10 < 10-15 < 15-20 < 20-25 < 25-30]
```

If you have data outside of the range you want, for example, some values between 0 and 1 which you don't want to include, then you might need to filter on your data before *cut*:

```
tipData = tipData[(tipData['tipPercent'] == 0) | ((tipData['tipPercent'] >= 1) & (tipData['tipPercent'] <= 30)]
```

In this way, your data would fall exclusively in the range you care about, then you can cut it use the method as above.

Comment: This solution is incorrect since your first bin is (-1, 1]. For v = 1 the output is 'No Tip'. you need to add 0, i.e. `tipBins = [-1, 0, 1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]`